# Cakephp undefined property error

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I am having an issue with a cakephp contoller I keep getting the error

Undefined property: AdsController::$getUrlsHTML

```
               public function getUrlsHTML($UrlId = 0) {
    // Called via AJAX to get HTML for CTAs
    // Provides insertable HTML based on list from getCalloutsActionsList()

    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $UrlsList = $this->getUrlsActionsList($UrlId);

    $this->set('Urls', $UrlsList);
    $this->set('url', $UrlId);
    $this->render('/elements/ads/url');
}

private function getUrlsActionsList($UrlId = 0) {
    // Pulls appropriate Callouts list. Usually called by getCalloutsHTML()

    $Urls = $this->getUrlsHTML->getUrls();

    $UrlsList = array();
    foreach ($Urls as $Url) {
        $UrlsList[$Url['url']['id']] = $Url['url']['text']; 
    }

    return $UrlsList ;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
$this->getUrlsHTML->getUrls();
```

is not valid. what are you trying to do?

The error says exactly what is your problem, `getUrlsHTML` is not a property, meaning "why are you treating it as a variable?"

Is either

```
$this->getUrlsHTML()
```

to call the function, or

```
$this->getUrlsHTML()->getUrls();
```

if you want to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Is the property "getUrlsHTML" declared in your controller? I can only see the function getUrlsHTML, so you have to call it using $this->getUrlsHTML().

Comment: I am trying to render a URL table in html via ajax thanks Nunser that helped.